# Simulation Nodes: How to collide convex hulls?

Tags: simulation-nodes

Geometry Nodes have a node for converting meshes in a collection into convex hull instances.

Can that be used with Simulation Nodes to make this happen?

[image]

I want to use Simulation Nodes further for what I'm trying to do. Rigid bodies are not an option. Making the parts in a collection to collide would be the first step.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to set up _Simulation Nodes_ to get some kind of rigid body like animation like the one shown in your question? Or just if you can use the _Convex Hull_ node in the _Simulation Nodes_? Well, it exists in _Geometry Nodes_, so why it should not be possible to use it?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann The question is the one with a question mark, naturally. Yes, I would love to know how to get some kind of rigid body like animation like the one shown in my question

Comment: Yes, the question mark... but it reads like "can convex hull be used?", the simple answer would be yes. I've seen many tutorials on doing physics simulations in _Geometry Nodes_, this is quite complex stuff and not a single issue easy to be solved in a single answer here. I guess you would rather need tutorials to achieve this so this is a bit out of scope for this site.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I've seen some setups with spheres used for getting collided, but not convex hulls yet. I think this is a relevant and small enough question - even though the answer could be quite complex. Hmm. I hope for the best, that somebody could answer it

Comment: Stupid question maybe on my behalf since I haven't seen the setups with spheres you're talking about: can the spheres not be replaced with other objects there?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I guess that's possible, but then the objects would be rotated in either all possible directions or only one direction for all, that would be my guess

Comment: Is it hard to replace the spheres by other objects? If not, why not simply test how they behave instead of guessing? Usually instances have the same mesh data, but they can be moved, rotated and scaled individually from each other. Like linked duplicates outside of _Geometry Nodes_, you can do all kinds of transforms differently for each duplicate in _Object Mode_, only changes in _Edit Mode_ affect the duplicates.